# PHP Fetch All Data Only 1 No

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch all users but not this user (id = 12) how to make this ?

```
$MyID = '12';
$sql_query = mysqli_query($Conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='$MyCountry'");
while ($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
    $firstname = $fetch_data['firstname'];
    echo $firstname;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in it's simplest form:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($Conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='$MyCountry' and userid <> $MyID");
```

But this is inadvisable because your values are not being escaped properly. Better to use prepared statements or mysqli_real_escape_string

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE country = ? and userId <> ?")
$stmt->bind_param("sd",$MyCountry, $MyId);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user WHERE  ID!=$mycountry;
```

Comment: really? didn't below answer is enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like that

lets say your field is an id = 12

then

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id <> 12
```